# How to get the number of rows affected by an UPDATE statement

Tags: oracle

I am trying to get the number of rows affected by an UPDATE statement, however I am getting the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   constant exception <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table columns long
   double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national
   character nchar
The symbol "exception" was substituted for ";" to continue.
```

The query that I am executing is the following:

```
DECLARE 
var_rows; 
BEGIN 
var_rows:=SQL%ROWCOUNT; 
UPDATE {Product} SET {Product}.[Name] = concat({Product}.[Name], ' - test') WHERE {Product}.[ProductTypeId] = 2; 
SELECT var_rows FROM DUAL; 
END;
```

Comment: If the table name is realy `{Product}` you'll have to double quote it... Same is valid for the column names `[Name]`, `[ProductTypeId]`.

Comment: The error you are getting seems to be just because you haven't given `var_rows` a data type - line 2 should be something like `var_rows pls_integer;`.  And then you should set `var_rows` *after* the update; and in  PL/SQL you need to select *into* something. Given your table/placeholder naming, it might be worth editing your question to show which client/application you are trying to run this from, and how - you might want `var_rows` to be a bind variable rather than a local variable, for example. or the client/driver might be able to give the count from a simple SQL update statement natively.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`SQL%rowcount`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/tdddg/stored-subprograms-packages.html#GUID-05FA9E55-F394-4A5F-A3C6-39EC0F68549F) properly. i.e. *immediately after* the `update`

**Example**

```
create table tab1 as 
select 1 id, 'a' col from dual union all
select 1, 'b' from dual;


set serveroutput on;
declare
 rn int;
begin 
   update tab1 
   set col = 'z';
   rn := SQL%rowcount; 
   dbms_output.put_line(rn);
end;
/
   
   2


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Now I'm getting ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Comment: Not with *my* example @rrruuuiii, you'll have to show *your* (updated) code.